# WinForms .NET TextRendered.DrawText, mixing bold and regular type clipped and misaligned

Tags: c#, winforms, gd, gdi+

I'm overriding a listbox DrawItem event where I need to highlight sometimes a single letter, sometimes whole words.

I have the code working good except for that the bold letters/words are not vertically aligned with the regular letters/words, they are shifted a few pixels to the bottom, I played with the formatting flags but still no go.

```
private void lstOptions_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Copy font from a textbox control placed on the form
    Font fontNormal = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    Font fontBold = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

    Rectangle textPos = e.Bounds;

    const TextFormatFlags formatFlags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.PathEllipsis;
    StringFormat strFormat = (StringFormat)StringFormat.GenericTypographic.Clone();
    strFormat.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;

    //Background
    e.DrawBackground();

    SizeF textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("Los Angeles", fontNormal, textPos.Width, strFormat);
    lstOptions.ItemHeight = int.Parse(Math.Ceiling(textSize.Height).ToString());

    //Drawing "L" Regular
    textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText("L", fontNormal, new Size(textPos.Width, textPos.Height), formatFlags);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "L", fontNormal, textPos, e.ForeColor, e.BackColor, formatFlags | TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping);
    textPos.X += MeasureText("L", fontNormal).Width;

    //Drawing "os" Bold
    textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText("o", fontBold, new Size(textPos.Width, textPos.Height), formatFlags);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "o", fontBold, textPos, e.ForeColor, e.BackColor, formatFlags | TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping);
    textPos.X += MeasureText("o", fontBold).Width;

    //Drawing " Angel" Regular
    textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText("s Ang", fontNormal, new Size(textPos.Width, textPos.Height), formatFlags);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "s Ang", fontNormal, textPos, e.ForeColor, e.BackColor, formatFlags | TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping);
    textPos.X += MeasureText("s Ang", fontNormal).Width;

    //Drawing "e" Bold
    textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText("ele", fontBold, new Size(textPos.Width, textPos.Height), formatFlags);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "ele", fontBold, textPos, e.ForeColor, e.BackColor, formatFlags | TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping);
    textPos.X += MeasureText("ele", fontBold).Width;

    //Drawing "s" Regular
    textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText("s", fontNormal, new Size(textPos.Width, textPos.Height), formatFlags);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "s", fontNormal, textPos, e.ForeColor, e.BackColor, formatFlags | TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping);
    textPos.X += MeasureText("s", fontNormal).Width;
}

public static Size MeasureText(string Text, Font Font)
{
    TextFormatFlags flags
      = TextFormatFlags.Left
      | TextFormatFlags.Top
      | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding
      | TextFormatFlags.NoPrefix;
    Size szProposed = new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);
    Size sz1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(".", Font, szProposed, flags);
    Size sz2 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text + ".", Font, szProposed, flags);
    return new Size(sz2.Width - sz1.Width, sz2.Height);
}
```

Sample Image:

http://i59.tinypic.com/25kn983.jpg

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `TextRenderer.MeasureText`?

Comment: I tried "textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Regular String", fontNormal);" but didn't work, I'm not sure how to use that effectively.

Comment: This snippet is inadequate, it doesn't show the essential part that tells us how you use textSize and update textPos.

Comment: I'm improving the snippet now.

Comment: Snippet improved, just copy and paste!

Comment: You are still mixing and matching your MeasureString and your TextRenderer.  These are different classes with potentially different outputs.  I wouldn't be setting the `lstOptions.ItemHeight` in a draw event of the control.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I don't know how to use TextRenderer.MeasureText, can you give me some advise?

Comment: Just pointing out consistency issues.  What is the font you are using and the size?

Comment: I appreciate that, I updated the snippet to use the TextRenderer class to measure the text, didn't fix it though. I'm using Arial 18pt on the textbox.

Comment: I'm no font expert, but Arial seems to be worse than any other font I try.

Comment: I tried sans serif but the horizontal spacing before and after the bold letters is way too much, I can't figure it out!

Comment: Horizontal Spacing or Vertical Spacing?  I though the issue was the vertical spacing since the letters weren't lining up correctly.

Comment: the horizontal spacing appeared after the last changes on the code.

Comment: MeasureText is bad at measuring single characters.  I hate to recommend the MeasureString function, but it works better in your case.

Comment: I think I'll have to start a new thread, after the latest changes using sans serif the spacing was corrected but there is some clipping occurring between the last bold font and the next regular font. I'm updating the Snippet now.

Comment: Please check the snippet now and the latest screenshot, the custom function to measure the text worked good however there is some clipping going on.

Answer (score 0):

My best results were achieved using this custom measure function found here on stackoverflow (can't find the link to the question anymore):

```
public static Size MeasureText(string Text, Font Font)
        {
            TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.Top
              | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.NoPrefix;

            StringFormat strFormat = (StringFormat)StringFormat.GenericDefault.Clone();
            strFormat.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;

            Size szProposed = new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);

            Size sz1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(".", Font, szProposed, flags);
            Size sz2 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text + ".", Font, szProposed, flags);

            if (Font.Bold)
                sz1.Width -= 1;

            return new Size(sz2.Width - sz1.Width, sz2.Height);
        }
```

This was very close but there was still some clipping going on on the bold fonts so I decided to ditch bold and go for underline to highlight the words and it looks much better:

```
Font fontMatch = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Underline);//Bold sucks on measuring the text
```